# How to implement a Clickable Widget for QListView?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I want to implement my own Widgets for a QListView. Like this:
[image]
If i click on this widget i want to do something.

In time, I only have experience with the QML-Version of the ListView.
Can someone explain how to insert this widget to the a QListView?

Greetings

**UPDATE**

In my Project i want a GUI like this:
[image]
In my first ListView I want to show items, that has a ListView, too. The text of each item can to be update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. Set custom widget for each index: [QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget). Note: there may be problems with interaction with widgets. This way is typically used only for displaying static content.
2. Create custom [QStyledItemDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and override editorEvent method. See [model-view programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html) for details.

Update:
I propose you next design:

1. Create widget with image list + "dynamic content" + labels
2. Create ScrollArea with vertical layout and add there widgets (1.)

(2.) is prefferable than simple listview, because listview doesn't design for such cases. Listview designed for showing some data, but not to be a container for other complex widgets.

Pros: you will have fully interactable widgets.

Cons: you need to code a bit ;)

Comment: Thank you. I also want to add a QListView to the item of a QListView. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended (imho, because you will have a lot of problems). I'm sure that there should be another solution - could you explain more exactly, what you want? (Possible, as another question)

Comment: thank you! Idea 2 is...simple...but GREAT! :) Thank you for your thread.  Maybe i want to sort my widgets by a range, later. In a ListView I can sort my items very efficient. Is this also available with the "vertical-layout-method"?

Comment: Yes, but you should do it manually :). It's just a few lines of code.